# Adding Logo To Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

Thanks for the help in advance---I've spent the greater part of a day trying to figure this one out. There are a few similar posts on stack overflow that I've tried but to no avail. I've been having issues trying to get a logo displayed when using the bootstrap navbar. My logo displays perfectly fine in development but when I push to heroku the logo and navbar overwhelm the upper portion of the page. I've also precompiled my assets so I don't think that is the issue.

The code in my _header.html.erb view looks like this:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to root_path, id: "logo" do %>
      <%= image_tag('doneLogo.jpg') %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

My CSS styling for the logo, in custom.css.scss, is as follows:

`#logo {
  padding-top: 1px;
  width: 180px;
}`

Any thoughts or idea are much appreciated. Let me know if any other information would be useful.

Comment: No one can really help with a snippet like that. (Avoid posting server side code with front end issues.) Ideally, post a full code example that shows what's happening, or link to an example page.

Comment: Will do in the future. Thanks for the advice.